# Ordered arguments with cmdargs

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

I would like to create a program who get some arguments with [cmdargs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs).
I would like to retrieve a list of filepath and list of actions to do. I needs these files to be taken and these actions to be perfomed **in order**.

My arguments are declared like this :

```
data Options = 
    Mode1   { 
              input :: [FilePath]
            , act1 :: Bool
            , act2 :: Bool
            , act3 :: Bool
            } deriving (Data, Typeable, Show, Eq)

mode1 = 
  Mode1 { 
            input   = []      &= name "i" &= help "input file"   &= typ "FILE"
          , act1    = False   &= name "a" &= help "action 1"     &= typ "ACTION"
          , act2    = False   &= name "b" &= help "action 2"     &= typ "ACTION"
          , act3    = False   &= name "c" &= help "action 3"     &= typ "ACTION"
        }
```

I managed to get the list of filepath in order with a list of `String` (`FilePath`). In this way I can get my input files ordered with  :

```
./myprog --input="file1.txt" --input="file2.txt"
./myprog --input="file2.txt" --input="file1.txt"
```

But I can't have my actions to be ordered as far as they are declared as `Bool`.
I would like to pass my arguments like this :

```
./myprog --act1 --act2 --act3 --input="file1.txt" --input="file2.txt"
./myprog --act3 --act1        --input="file1.txt" --input="file2.txt"
./myprog --act2 --act3 --act1 --input="file1.txt" --input="file2.txt"
```

to get differents output results.

**Is it possible with cmdargs to retrieve differents arguments in order ?**

Comment: Looks like these were removed in the last few versions
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.13/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-GetOpt.html#v:Permute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible with cmdargs to retrieve differents arguments in order ?

Yes, with [`enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.13/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html#v:enum).

```
$ runhaskell ~/testargs.hs -a -b -1 "~" -c -a
Mode1 {input = ["~"], acts = [ActA,ActB,ActC,ActA]}
```

Using :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import System.Console.CmdArgs

data Act = 
    ActA
  | ActB
  | ActC
  deriving (Show, Typeable,  Data, Eq)

data Options = Mode1
  { input :: [FilePath]
  , acts :: [Act]
  } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable, Eq)

actsDef :: [Act]
actsDef = (enum
  [ [] &= ignore
  , [ActA] &= name "a" &= help "action a"
  , [ActB] &= name "b" &= help "action b" 
  , [ActC] &= name "c" &= help "action c" 
  ]) &= typ "ACTION"

mode :: Options
mode = Mode1
  { input = [] &= name "1" &= help "input file" &= typ "FILE"
  , acts = actsDef 
  }

main = print =<< cmdArgs mode
```