# Ordered arguments with values in cmdargs

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

This question is an extension of the topic : [Ordered arguments with cmdargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288777/ordered-arguments-with-cmdargs)

I managed to have a list of argument of the same type. But nom, I would like to have a list of options with values. like this :

```
runhaskell ~/testargs.hs -a 5,6 -b 8,9 -c 4,2 -a 9,3
```

I tried to declare my data with

```
data Act = 
    ActA (Double,Double)
  | ActB (Double,Double)
  | ActC (Double,Double)
  deriving (Show, Typeable,  Data, Eq)
```

but I get the following error :

```
Couldn't match expected type `Act'
    with actual type `(Double, Double) -> Act'
In the expression: ActA
```

**Is it possible to retrieve a list of argument with values ?**

Comment: That error is due to an expression, but you haven't showed us the context in which the expression was used, so it's impossible to determine what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will have to use the lower-level `Explicit` api to do this.

Here is an example which shows how to use the Explicit api to:

- handle **--help**
- collect multiple **-w ...** options
- validate a flag's parameter
- collect all unnamed arguments

Usage examples:

```
prog --help
prog -i=456
prog -w this -w is -w a -w test
prog -i=xyz
```

Program:

```
import System.Console.CmdArgs.Explicit
import Data.Char

data MyOptions = Opts { _help    :: Bool
                      , _words   :: [String]
                      , _opt1    :: String
                      , _opt2    :: Int
                      , _unnamed :: [ String ]
                      }
  deriving (Show)

myMode :: Mode MyOptions
myMode = mode "programName" initialOpts  description unnamedArg convertFlags
  where
    initialOpts = Opts False [] "abc" 3 []
    description = "This program does it all."

    unnamedArg = Arg { argValue = updateUnnamed, argType = "<FILE>", argRequire = False }
        where updateUnnamed str opts = Right $ opts { _unnamed = (str : _unnamed opts) }

    updateWord str opts = Right $ opts { _words = (str: _words opts) }
    updateA    str opts = Right $ opts { _opt1 = str }
    updateNum  str opts 
      | not (null str) && all isDigit str = Right $ opts { _opt2 = read str }
      | otherwise                         = Left $ "-i option is not a number: " ++ str

    convertFlags =
       [ flagReq     ["w","word"] updateWord "<WORD>"   "add a word"
       , flagReq     ["a", "bc"]  updateA    "<STRING>" "a string option"
       , flagOpt "0" ["i" ]       updateNum  "<NUMBER>" "a numeric option"
       , flagHelpSimple (\opts -> opts { _help = True })
       ]

main = do
   opts <- processArgs myMode
   print opts
   if _help opts then
       print $ helpText [] HelpFormatDefault myMode
    else
       print opts
```